# Understanding a countermodel to $∀x∃yAxy→∃y∀xAxy$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

The truth tree generator [https://www.umsu.de/trees/#~6x~7yAxy~5~7y~6xAxy](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%7E6x%7E7yAxy%7E5%7E7y%7E6xAxy)
is providing the countermodel

Domain: { 0, 1 }
A:  { (0,0), (1,1) }

to show that  $$∀x∃yAxy → ∃y∀xAxy$$ is an invalid sentence.

I don't understand how this is a countermodel that shows that the formula is invalid. Can someone help me understand why, please?

Answer (score 2):

The given set in the answer is the set where predicate $A$ is true.

Otherwise said, the countermodel can be expressed in the following way

$$\begin{cases}A00, \ A11 \ \text{are true} ;\\A01, \ A10 \ \text{are false} \end{cases}.$$

In this context, the left hand side formula is valid, whereas the right hand side is not because no $y$ satisfies it, indeed:

- taking $y=0$, you cannot say $\forall x, Ax0$ because it is false for $x=1$,
- taking $y=1$, you cannot say $\forall x, Ax1$ because it is false for $x=0$.

Comment: Could you say how one can have some more information about this proof generator ?

Comment: Thanks. But I still do not see why it is the case that **taking =0, you cannot say ∀,0 because it is false for =1**. Why does x and y have to be the same for the formula to be valid?

Comment: and regarding your question about the generator, I really don't know. I came across it while searching online!

Comment: "*Why does $x$ and $y$ have to be the same for the formula to be valid?*" In the given countermodel, the predicate $Axy$ is defined such that it is true iff $x=y$ (equivalently, $Axy$ := $x=y$). The given formula's consequent (RHS) is false because neither $Ax0$ nor $Ax1$ is universally true.

Comment: @ryang It is indeed a way to answer the question.

Comment: It is good to know the existence of other proof generators, like these ones: https://www.taut-logic.com/index.html , 
https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/ , 
https://mrieppel.github.io/fitchjs/ , 
http://teachinglogic.liglab.fr/DN/index.php